# Sync sftp folder with local folder

Tags: javascript, node.js

So I am trying to make my sftp folder synced with a local folder using nodejs. That means that they both always have the same files and also get updated based on which one is newer. The Problem I have with my script is that it is always uploading the folders and files even if I haven't changed anything. Maybe the date is different?

```
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
const Client = require('ssh2-sftp-client');

const SFTP_CONFIG = {
  host: '123456',
  username: 'user',
  password: '1234',
  port: 22,
  remotePath: '/',
  localPath: './content',
  syncInterval: 10000, 
};

const sftp = new Client();

async function syncFiles() {
  try {
    await sftp.connect(SFTP_CONFIG);

    await syncDirectory(SFTP_CONFIG.remotePath, SFTP_CONFIG.localPath);

    setInterval(async () => {
      await syncDirectory(SFTP_CONFIG.remotePath, SFTP_CONFIG.localPath);
    }, SFTP_CONFIG.syncInterval);
  } catch (err) {
    console.error('Error:', err);
  }
}

async function syncDirectory(remotePath, localPath) {
  try {
    const remoteFiles = await sftp.list(remotePath);
    const localFiles = await getLocalFiles(localPath);

    // Download new or modified files from the remote server
    for (const remoteFile of remoteFiles) {
      const localFile = localFiles.find((f) => f.name === remoteFile.name);
      if (!localFile || remoteFile.modifyTime > localFile.modifyTime) {
        const remoteFilePath = path.posix.join(remotePath, remoteFile.name);
        const localFilePath = path.join(localPath, remoteFile.name);
        if (remoteFile.type === 'd') {
          await downloadDirectory(remoteFilePath, localFilePath);
        } else {
          await downloadFile(remoteFilePath, localFilePath);
        }
      } else if (remoteFile.modifyTime < localFile.modifyTime) {
        const remoteFilePath = path.posix.join(remotePath, remoteFile.name);
        const localFilePath = path.join(localPath, remoteFile.name);
        if (localFile.type === 'd') {
          await uploadDirectory(localFilePath, remoteFilePath);
        } else {
          await uploadFile(localFilePath, remoteFilePath);
        }
      }
    }

    // Upload new or modified files to the remote server
    for (const localFile of localFiles) {
      const remoteFile = remoteFiles.find((f) => f.name === localFile.name);
      if (!remoteFile || localFile.modifyTime > remoteFile.modifyTime) {
        const remoteFilePath = path.posix.join(remotePath, localFile.name);
        const localFilePath = path.join(localPath, localFile.name);
        if (localFile.type === 'd') {
          await uploadDirectory(localFilePath, remoteFilePath);
        } else {
          await uploadFile(localFilePath, remoteFilePath);
        }
      }
    }
  } catch (err) {
    console.error('Error syncing directory:', err);
  }
}

async function downloadFile(remotePath, localPath) {
  try {
    await sftp.fastGet(remotePath, localPath);
    console.log(`Downloaded ${remotePath} to ${localPath}`);
  } catch (err) {
    console.error('Error downloading file:', err);
  }
}

async function downloadDirectory(remotePath, localPath) {
  try {
    await fs.promises.mkdir(localPath, { recursive: true });

    const remoteFiles = await sftp.list(remotePath);
    for (const remoteFile of remoteFiles) {
      const fileName = remoteFile.name;
      const remoteFilePath = path.posix.join(remotePath, fileName);
      const localFilePath = path.join(localPath, fileName);
      if (remoteFile.type === 'd') {
        await downloadDirectory(remoteFilePath, localFilePath);
      } else {
        await downloadFile(remoteFilePath, localFilePath);
      }
    }
  } catch (err) {
    console.error('Error downloading directory:', err);
  }
}

async function uploadFile(localPath, remotePath) {
  try {
    await sftp.fastPut(localPath, remotePath);
    console.log(`Uploaded ${localPath} to ${remotePath}`);
  } catch (err) {
    console.error('Error uploading file:', err);
  }
}

async function uploadDirectory(localPath, remotePath) {
  try {
    await sftp.mkdir(remotePath, true);
    console.log(`Uploaded ${localPath} to ${remotePath}`);
    const localFiles = await getLocalFiles(localPath);
    for (const localFile of localFiles) {
      const fileName = localFile.name;
      const localFilePath = path.join(localPath, fileName);
      const remoteFilePath = path.posix.join(remotePath, fileName);
      if (localFile.type === 'd') {
        await uploadDirectory(localFilePath, remoteFilePath);
      } else {
        await uploadFile(localFilePath, remoteFilePath);
      }
    }
  } catch (err) {
    console.error('Error uploading directory:', err);
  }
}

async function getLocalFiles(dirPath) {
  try {
    const files = await fs.promises.readdir(dirPath, { withFileTypes: true });
    return Promise.all(
      files.map(async (file) => {
        const filePath = path.join(dirPath, file.name);
        const stats = await fs.promises.stat(filePath);
        return { name: file.name, modifyTime: stats.mtimeMs, type: file.isDirectory() ? 'd' : 'f' };
      })
    );
  } catch (err) {
    if (err.code === 'ENOENT') {
      console.error(`Local path "${dirPath}" does not exist.`);
      return [];
    } else {
      console.error('Error reading local directory:', err);
      throw err;
    }
  }
}

syncFiles();
```

Comment: Radically different suggestion: just use rsync?

Comment: Or [Syncthing](https://syncthing.net)